# Simple table creation sql works for mysql and postgre, but reported errors in oracle

Tags: python, mysql, oracle, postgresql

I am using Python with cx_Oracle to work with Oracle 11g.

I have following SQL work well with MySQL/PostgreSQL,

```
stock_info_create = 'CREATE TABLE STOCK_INFO(' + \
                    'CODE    VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,' + \
                    'NAME    VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,' + \
                    'TIMETOMARKET VARCHAR2(255),' + \
                    'PRIMARY KEY (CODE)' + \
                    ');'
```

And the returned message was

```
(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00911: invalid character
[SQL: 'CREATE TABLE STOCK_INFO(CODE    VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,NAME    VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,TIMETOMARKET VARCHAR2(255),PRIMARY KEY (CODE));']
```

Of course, to use this sql for Oracle I changed VARCHAR to VARCHAR2 since I thought the error was caused by wrong data type. But after changing to VARCHAR2 it still didn't work.

Another problem is with table creation as well.

```
stock_h_create = 'CREATE TABLE STOCK_H_NONE(' + \
                 'CODE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,' + \
                 'DATE DATE,' + \
                 'OPEN FLOAT,' + \
                 'HIGH FLOAT,' + \
                 'CLOSE FLOAT,' + \
                 'LOW FLOAT,' + \
                 'VOLUME FLOAT,' + \
                 'AMOUNT FLOAT,' + \
                 'AUTYPE VARCHAR(16),' + \
                 'LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,' + \
                 'PRIMARY KEY (CODE,AUTYPE,DATE)' + \
                 ');'
```

The returned message was

```
Creating table STOCK_H_NONE... (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
[SQL: 'CREATE TABLE STOCK_H_NONE(CODE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,DATE DATE,OPEN FLOAT,HIGH FLOAT,CLOSE FLOAT,LOW FLOAT,VOLUME FLOAT,AMOUNT FLOAT,AUTYPE VARCHAR(16),LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,PRIMARY KEY (CODE,AUTYPE,DATE));']
```

I appreciate any kind of help and your visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain reserved words in Oracle are not allowed to be used as column names - data types are among those reserved words, e.g. `Date`, `Number`. You got an "ORA-00904: invalid identifier" error because of your `Date` column. For good practice, try and avoid using reserved words as column names.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to change NAME to something else like SNAME but it still returns the same error message. Also, I directly copy and paste the sql query in the error message to sql-developer and run it. The table is created successfully. Are there any other possible problems?

Comment: Try getting rid of the semi-colon in the string - that can cause the "invalid character" error.

Comment: You are the superstar now lol. Errors gone. That's so weird, when I was in school we used python2.7 with cx_Oracle, at that moment it did require the semi-colon...

Comment: @Kulbear Not a problem! Be sure and mark as the correct answer if this is resolved for you.